# MSIE is making my slidejs code look horrible

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I am building a web page that uses slidejs image slider to show a series of images.

When I run my page from firefox and safari the page looks the way it should.  However, when I run the same code from within MSIE 9, it looks horrible.  IE is putting borders around my slidejs images and buttons.   I went through all my css and turned off every border I could find, but still MSIE makes it look terrible.

Page: http://107.22.173.10/print.html
  user: test2
  login: abc111

Any ideas why this is happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the border in CSS b/c IE typically adds borders to image href's... Something below should work:

```
a img {border: none; }
```

Most people use a reset stylesheet to correct issues like this and others before using their own css.

Comment: Thanks that worked...  I wonder if there's anything else that MSIE is doing that I need to fix?

Answer (score 1):

Add the css outline property if a img {border: none; } not works for you.

```
outline: none;
```